# Adding import declarations to the right position

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I am trying to add import declarations to a compilation unit for the types referenced in a newly created method declaration. For this purpose I created a simple ASTVisitor that adds every type (Simple type, parameterized type etc) that it visits to a given ImportRewrite instance. To add the changes that I have done to the compilation unit to a MultiTextEdit instance, I first add the changes to the ASTRewrite instance via using the rewriteAST() method and then the changes to the ImportRewrite via using the rewriteImports() method. The code below:

```
MultiTextEdit edit = new MultiTextEdit();
TextEdit astEdit = astRewrite.rewriteAST();
edit.addChild(astEdit);
TextEdit importEdit = importRewrite.rewriteImports(new NullProgressMonitor());
edit.addChild(importEdit);
```

Also, one part of the visitor is (the other types follow the same pattern):

```
public boolean visit(SimpleType type) {
    ITypeBinding typeBinding = type.resolveBinding();
    importRewrite.addImport(typeBinding);
    return true;
}
```

The problem is that in the newly created compilation unit, the import declarations are positioned after all the other type declarations etc. resulting in compile errors. As stated in the documentation no import declaration is edited by the ASTRewrite. I tried to add the importRewrite changes before the astRewrite changes resulting in import declarations that are positioned before the package declaration, thus again resulting in compile error. Any ideas on how to fix the problem and add the import declarations on the right place between the package declaration and the type declarations?

Answer (score 0):

for some reason, the IDE is thinking your type declarations are comments! That's why it is putting them after them.